# Expanding and collapsing multiple DIV elements depending on selected

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help with JavaScript. This needs to be changed.

My HTML has a dropddown list with a default selection of  "choose one"

- New User
- Previous User
- Existing User

I have 4 `div` in my html id new / previous / existing  and existinginfo

the page starts with all `div`'s closed but I would like to alter the code to amend them to show depending on what drop down list is picked.

If the selection drop down list is `New user` only "NEW" `div` is shown others are closed.

`Previous user`- **NEW** and **PREVIOUS** `div`'s are shown others are closed.

`existing user` existing `div` is shown and existinginfo `div` is shown (new and previous are closed).

I believe i need to have a additional functions which are copies of my slideuprunnew/slidedownRunnew functions with the addtional names (ie slideuprunPrev and SlideDownRunPrev) but I am having a lot of problems working out how to do the `Slide()` function and correctly nesting all the if.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var sliderIntervalId = 0;
 var sliderHeight = 1;
 var sliding = false;
 var slideSpeed = 5;

 function Slide() {
     var selected = document.getElementById('selection');
     if (sliding)
         return;
     sliding = true;

     if (sliderHeight == 150 && selected.value != "new user")
         sliderIntervalId = setInterval('SlideUpRunNEW()', 30);
     else {

         if (selected.value == "new user")
             sliderIntervalId = setInterval('SlideDownRunNEW()', 30);

         else {
             sliding = false;
             return;
         }
     }
 }


 function SlideUpRunNEW() {
     slider = document.getElementById('new');
     if (sliderHeight <= 1) {
         sliding = false;
         sliderHeight = 1;
         slider.style.height = '1px';
         clearInterval(sliderIntervalId);
     }
     else {
         sliderHeight -= slideSpeed;
         if (sliderHeight < 1)
             sliderHeight = 1;
         slider.style.height = sliderHeight + 'px';
     }
 }

 function SlideDownRunNEW() {
     slider = document.getElementById('new');
     if (sliderHeight >= 150) {
         sliding = false;
         sliderHeight = 150;
         slider.style.height = '150px';
         clearInterval(sliderIntervalId);
     }
     else {
         sliderHeight += slideSpeed;
         if (sliderHeight > 150)
             sliderHeight = 150;
         slider.style.height = sliderHeight + 'px';
     }
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/uZcTH/

I used JQuery, if you need only pure javascript, then these are not the droids you are looking for.

**JS**

```
 $("#newUser").show();
 $("#previousUser").hide();
 $("#existingUser").hide();

 $("#userPicker").change(function () {
     var val = $(this).val();
     switch (val) {
         case "1":
             $("#newUser").show();
             $("#previousUser").hide();
             $("#existingUser").hide();
             break;
         case "2":
             $("#newUser").hide();
             $("#previousUser").show();
             $("#existingUser").hide();
             break;
         case "3":
             $("#newUser").hide();
             $("#previousUser").hide();
             $("#existingUser").show();
             break;
     }
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="userPicker">
    <option value="1">New User</option>
    <option value="2">Previous User</option>
    <option value="3">Existing User</option>
</select>
<div id="newUser">new user</div>
<div id="previousUser">previous user</div>
<div id="existingUser">existing user</div>
```

hope it helps, regards

---

**EDIT**

pure js version here: http://jsfiddle.net/uZcTH/2/

**CODE**

```
document.getElementById("newUser").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("previousUser").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("existingUser").style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("userPicker").onchange = function () {
    switch (this.selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("newUser").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("previousUser").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("existingUser").style.display = "none";
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("newUser").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("previousUser").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("existingUser").style.display = "none";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("newUser").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("previousUser").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("existingUser").style.display = "block";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really like the way this works and i think it'll be really useful for me but for this problem i cant use jquery it has to be javascript. still i really like this answer but sadly its not helpful to me this time round.

Comment: you sir! are a STAR! both worked with slight tweaking to the html code and i managed to find out that i can use jquery so i was able to use that.. also added a default case to the end of the case to hid all of the div, and wrapped the jquery in a doc ready function. :)